# Get the included path in same program

Tags: c, gcc

Suppose I have a program

**main.c**

```
#include "file.h" 
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
//Code to found the included path
}

gcc -I /local main.c
```

How can I found the included path of header file inside this program
Now their can be 3 included path

1. current directory
2. ENV set in the Path VARIABLE or other
3. Directory included with -I option

Please provide a way to get this inside the same program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079650/how-can-i-find-the-header-files-of-the-c-programming-language-in-linux/13080356#13080356

Comment: That question is about the user finding out where the include files were found, he wants the program itself to get the info.

Comment: I don't think C provides this kind of introspection mechanism. There are multiple include files, which one should be "the included path"? BTW, the PATH environment variable isn't used to find include files.

Comment: There is really no reason why you should need the include paths inside an application.

Comment: @Daniel Kamil Kozar I need that kind of info as i am using that in my programm.

Comment: @user1471175: if you explain _why_ you need that, maybe people can find ways to do what you want. As it is, it's really unclear what you'd do with that information at runtime.

Comment: @Barmer Their must be any mechanism for that?

Comment: @Mat I have some header files in that path, which i need to parse in my programm. In a more clear way you can say that a programm need to parse all the linked header files which were used in the compilation of the programm and i dont want the path to be static (or preassumed as can be written to a file), I want all this in a dynamic way. Is their any way it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the include files that you could edit you can use the `__FILE__` macro. It makes the preprocessor insert the full file's name like `/the/directory/filename`.

Just add the follow line to you header:

```
static const char MyIncludeFileName[] = __FILE__;
```

If you do not refer to `MyIncludeFileName` (from the code which includes the header) the compiler might issue a warning that `MyIncludeFileName` is declared but not used. To tell the compiler be quiet about this do the followings:

```
static const char MyIncludeFileName[] __attribute__ ((unused)) = __FILE__;
```

Comment: Just as a side note : `__attribute__ ((unused))` doesn't work on MSVC. :)