# How to use the command man in linux to get the manual of the libraries used by C?

Tags: manpage

I have tried to get the manual for the function `stdint.h` typing `$ man stdint` and `$ man 3 stdint` but doesn't work. I get nothing. And I have tried the same for some of their functions like `int8_t` but I still getting nothing.

Although I am able to find those manuals online, I would like to know how to do that in the terminal.

What is wrong? What is the correct way?

Comment: Make sure you've actually installed all the relevant man pages.  Some distros don't install them by default.  You can use `apropos stdint` to do a search.  Here, it tells me to ask for `stdint.h`, and `man stdint.h` works.

Comment: stdint.h is a header, not a function. Similarly, intXX_t are type names, not a function. So, man pages only indirectly describes them, only at least for ubuntu. It seems certain unix variants have this one listed under man page 7 under macros and conventions. But, for linux variants such as ubuntu, what you can do about them is type "vim /usr/include/stdint.h" and read the source code there.

Answer (score 1):

To expand my comment, the standard man search command is `apropos`.

Example:

```
$ apropos stdint
stdint.h (0p)        - integer types
```

This tells you the title of the man page that matches your query is `stdint.h`, located in section `0p`.  If no pages can be found, it says `nothing appropriate`.

`apropos` can't always search the "fresh" man pages.  It queries a cache that is typically built by a cron job.  Freshly installed man pages may not become searchable until the next cache update.

Comment: I have done that but I get `nothing appropate`. Could you tell me what is the best way to install `stdint.h` and other headers and functions?

Comment: @Aaron-S, I'd suggest try consulting your distro's package database.  This is highly distro-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* that you do not have the library `stdint.h` installed on your machine. To see if it exists see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079650/how-can-i-find-the-header-files-of-the-c-programming-language-in-linux), & also check the `#include` files which are generally in the directory `/usr/include`.